# Extract width and height from image links via ImgApp Google Sheet Library

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, url, data-extraction

I want to extract the dimensions of the image from the URL in google Sheet. Found this Library that does exactly what I am after.

https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#getsize

But I am very new to this scenario and wondering what exactly I should use in the script editor. If I follow the above I can't get the results.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my library was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I would like to study more. About `If I follow the above I can't get the results.`, I cannot understand it. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike Please don't apologize. Your Image App Library is awesome. I just wish I get the same answers as your demo. This is the sample file. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dcqVH885CgRiXVSWgZ6abvayAc6_D7lW9vW9VQSm98s/edit?usp=sharing. I want to know what I should exactly add in the script editor.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing more information. From your added information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the Spreadsheet and your script are as follows.

[image]

```
function myFunction() {

var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
var res = ImgApp.getSize(blob);
var width = res.width;
var height = res.height;

}
```

#### Modification points:

- In this case, you put a custom function of `=myFunction(A2)` to a cell. But your script doesn't retrieve the value.
- At the custom function, `DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)` cannot be used because of the limitation.
- Your script doesn't return the values.

When these points are reflected in the script for achieving your goal, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please replace your current script with the following script and save the script. And, please put a custom function of `=myFunction(A2)` to a cell. By this, the width and height are returned.

```js
function myFunction(url) {
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  const { width, height } = ImgApp.getSize(blob);
  return [[width, height]];
}
```

#### Testing:

When this modified script is used for your sample Spreadsheet, it becomes as follows.

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [ImgApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp#getsize)

Comment: Awesome!. Thank you so much for your fast reply and you have an amazing talent. Thanks Again. Cheers!

Comment: @Divya Ravishanker Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.